# Make matlab code more efficient

Tags: matlab, montecarlo

Just started to code in matlab because I am studying the book *An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation* by Higham. One of the example codeblocks he gives ([this is the source](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/d.j.higham/ch21.m)) is:

```
V = zeros(M,1);                                                                 
Vanti = zeros(M,1);                                                             
for i = 1:M                                                                     
    samples = randn(N,1);                                                       

    % standard Monte Carlo                                                      
    Svals = S*cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt+sigma*sqrt(Dt)*samples));          
    Smax = max(Svals);                                                          
    if Smax < B                                                                 
       V(i) = exp(-r*T)*max(Svals(end)-E,0);                                    
    end                                                                         

    % antithetic path                                                           
    Svals2 = S*cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt-sigma*sqrt(Dt)*samples));         
    Smax2 = max(Svals2);                                                        
    V2 = 0;                                                                     
    if Smax2 < B                                                                
       V2 = exp(-r*T)*max(Svals2(end)-E,0);                                     
    end                                                                         
    Vanti(i) = 0.5*(V(i) + V2);                                                 

end
```

I am trying to get this loop more efficient, so I am trying to remove the for loop. This is what I wrote so far:

```
V = zeros(M,1);                                                                 
Vanti = zeros(M,1);                                                             
samples = randn(N,M);                                                           
Svals = S*cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt+sigma*sqrt(Dt)*samples));              
Svals2 = S*cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt-sigma*sqrt(Dt)*samples));             
Send = Svals(end,:);                                                            
Send2 = Svals2(end,:);                                                          
Smax = max(Svals);                                                              
Smax2 = max(Svals2);                                                            
V2 = zeros(M,1);                                                                   
for i = 1:M                                                                        
    if Smax(i) < B                                                                 
       V(i) = exp(-r*T)*max(Send(i)-E,0);                                          
    end                                                                            
    if Smax2(i) < B                                                                
       V2(i) = exp(-r*T)*max(Send2(i)-E,0);                                        
    end                                                                            

end                                                                                
Vanti = 0.5*(V + V2);                                                              
aM = mean(V); bM = std(V);                                                         
conf = [aM - 1.96*bM/sqrt(M), aM + 1.96*bM/sqrt(M)]                                
aManti = mean(Vanti); bManti = std(Vanti);                                                                             
confanti = [aManti - 1.96*bManti/sqrt(M), aManti + 1.96*bManti/sqrt(M)]         
toc
```

This already made the code significantly quicker, because there aren't any randn variables generated inside the loop. I don't know however, how I am able to remove the other part of the loop. Is it even possible?

Comment: Hmm that obviously isn't what I intended to achieve. But are you sure? I thought it works since I generate M,N samples?

Comment: Oh, terribly sorry, I missed that change. You're doing fine:) Sorry again. You might try using `samples` the other way around: accessing a contiguous column is faster than accessing a contiguous row (since array storage in matlab is column-major). Also: you can try using `profile` to see which part of your code takes the most amount of time (though it's not always reliable, especially for fast programs).

Comment: Also, since everything in calculation of `Svals` is scalar, save for `samples`, you can calculate the terms pre-loop.  Like: `alpha1 = cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt+sigma*sqrt(Dt)*samples),2)` and then `Svals=S*alpha1(i,:);`.

Comment: @TroyHaskin and from there I'm pretty sure the whole loop can be done away with.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated the code with your suggestions. I am stuck with those last 5 lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest using `max(Svals,1)` explicitly to avoid confusion. And you can use logical indexing: `V=zeros(M,1); V(Smax<B)=exp(-r*T)*max(Send(Smax<B)-E,0)`. And of course make sure in the end that the code produces the reasonably same result:)